# Some information about your app is incomplete. Please check the following sections: Store listing

Tags: android

I would like to add testers to my play store beta testing for one of my already existed app on play store. When I opened release management- app releases has been disabled and showing a warning message on the top of the screen like below-

Some information about your app is incomplete.
Please check the following sections:
Store listing

Then i opened store preferences-store listing. All the data and fileds has been filled. Nothing has been missed. But why i am getting this kind of error.

Still i tried to update the store listing details and trying to submit update then i got below error-

The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors.

Please anyone can suggest and help me to getover from this problem. Why i am receiving these two messages?

Comment: Make sure ALL fields with a asteriks (*) have been filled in. Sometimes you can miss one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @Yamini: Please check your content rating section. If you have provided that, then check if you have provided a privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a privacy policy document and add the link to document in 
Store listing --> Privacy Policy.
The are a lot of free generators on Internet.

The best way to expose the document via Internet is Google Drive.

Answer (score -1):

Give any link like(https://www.google.com/) and Click on Sublimt Update
[image]

Remove the unnecessary Permissions(If you have) and upload your new application and select the check box in Privacy Policy.
[image]